# Docking my menu to the top of the form

Tags: wpf, menu

I am trying to learn WPF and am struggling with a few concepts. I have not managed to work it out.

This is the XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="OCLMEditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OCLMEditor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="517.366" Width="729.7">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,119">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="24,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="670">
            <Menu x:Name="menuOCLM" Height="38">
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="Download Schedule Information"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Export Student Information"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Import Student Information"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Page Setup"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Print Preview"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Update Google Calendar"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                <MenuItem Header="View"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Options"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
            </Menu>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: Menu]

But I want this menu bar to be just the height it needs and take the full width of the form. I thought I had to use a `StackPanel` but can't get it right.

Comment: that is what you get when have a fixed size: `Height="100" Margin="24,10,0,0"  Width="670"`. remove these attributes and see the difference

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.  I will get it in the end ... :)